# IOS- Pop-up with storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uialertview

I'm using storyboard and i want to add a popup to my app.

My popup will contain a slider (which i need to get his value), and also cancel option ('x' at top of the popup).

What is the best way to do that?

- ViewController?
- Xib file?
- View?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to create a popup, button & slider in your code. Than you have more control over it. It's easier to access your slider & to dismiss the popover in the same code.

Put this code in the IBAction function when a button is pressed from where you want the popover:

```
//Create a popovercontroller
UIPopovercontroller *popOverController;

//Create an instance of the class you working in, your viewcontroller
YourViewController *popOverContent = [[YourViewController alloc] init];

//Create the popover view, you can change the size of it
UIView *popOverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
UISLider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
UIButton *close = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)]

//Add slider & button to view
[popOverView addSubview:slider];
[popOverView addSubview:button];

//Add view to viewcontroller
[popOverContent addSubview:popOverView];

//Alloc & init the popovercontroller
popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popOverContent];

//Set content size of popover
popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);

//present popup from a button or frame
[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.yourButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Than create an IBAction for the close button and use this line of code to dismiss the popover:

```
[popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

You can find more information about popOverControllers [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with your popup and how do you want to present it you can choose:

1. ViewController from storyboard if you want to present a popup in `modal style` and from that popup you want to show other view controllers.
2. Xib file for a custom UIView, if you are using the popup to display some information and get the user input after that you will dismiss the popup and the popup will be used in several places (different view controllers)
3. Custom UIView in one storyboard view controller, if you want to display some information and get the user input and the popup will be use only on one place (one ViewController)